# Come around vs come here

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, difference, phrase-usage, collocations

To me it seems like *come around* mean come anywhere near to me in any direction, that is behind me, right in front of me, sideways etc. On the other hand, *come here* seems to imply to come at a specific spot near me.

So, what is the actual difference between *come around* and *come here*?

Comment: There's no need to guess, you can just look it up: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+around

Comment: @userr2684291 I checked it, but it explains other meanings. I have noticed people using it in place of come here, like when someone needs me he says come around, it's not like I visit their place to meet them.

Comment: **Come here** is as you say. **Come around** is most often followed by  phrases such as: to my place, to our house, to the club, to the hall etc

Comment: You should add some example phrases to your question, and how the meaning in each is not clear.

Comment: "Come here" and "Come around",, have been covered as far as may be without the OP providing additional information. The definition that the OP gives for "Come around" would appear to me to a possible definition for "Gather round".

Comment: @James I don't have any other information. It's just that I noticed people using this phrase.

Comment: @user31782  Fair enough.  As you have no doubt found out, 'come around' can mean several different things, depending on the context in which it is used. The link provided by  userr2684291 gives a good summary of them. Had you seen, or heard, this phrase used in a specific sentence, then knowing that sentence would have made it easier for one of us to determine which of these meanings was applicable. For the record, I have never heard 'come around' used to mean 'form a circle around me' as you thought. Also 'come around' is sometimes written as 'come round'.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not easy to answer is that 'come around' is used in many different ways and can mean many different things, as you've discovered in the dictionary.

You're correct that 'come here' is more specific than 'come around', and if you want to know the meaning of 'come around' then trust what you find in a reputable dictionary. You've answered your own question.

BTW - my first thought was the meaning you rejected in your comment. 'Come around' often means to come for a visit.